# Display validation message with ng-messages based on multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, ng-messages

I use angular ng-messages to display validation messages

Consider the following code:

```
<ul ng-messages="formToValidate.fieldToValidate.$error" ng-messages-multiple>
    <li ng-message="pattern">Invalid pattern</li>
    <li ng-message="minlength, maxlength">Should contain no less than 7 and no more than 100 chars</li>
    <li ng-message="!pattern && !minlength && !maxlength && onlyAfterAllOtherPassedValidation">
        This validation message is shown only when all the other validations have passed and validation  fails on onlyAfterAllOtherPassedValidation
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to  show the last validation message only if all other validations have passed and validation  fails on onlyAfterAllOtherPassedValidation.
And I do not know whether it's possible at all to pass complex condition to ng-message 
Any suggestions as well as workarounds are welcomed as long as I still can use ng-messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use ng-if on the element holding the message, eg

```
<li ng-if="!formToValidate.fieldToValidate.$error.required && !formToValidate.fieldToValidate.$error.minLength && !formToValidate.fieldToValidate.$error.maxLength" ng-message="onlyAfterAllOtherPassedValidation">
    This validation message is shown only when all the other validations have passed and validation  fails on onlyAfterAllOtherPassedValidation
</li>
```

Comment: Works for me, didn't think even about it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by **JonMac1374** of course work. But it is better to solve this problem once and for all. I advise you to pay attention to the directive [use-form-error](https://github.com/Stepan-Kasyanenko/use-form-error). It helps to build their own check.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/rs0e8wu2/).

```
<form name="ExampleForm">
  <label>Password</label>
  <input ng-model="password" name="password" minlength="2" pattern="^\d*$" required use-form-error="onlyAfterAllOtherPassedValidation" use-error-expression="!ExampleForm.password.$error.required && !ExampleForm.password.$error.minlength && !ExampleForm.password.$error.pattern"
  />
  <pre>{{ExampleForm.password.$error|json}}</pre>
  <div ng-messages="ExampleForm.password.$error" ng-messages-multiple="true" class="errors">
    <div ng-message="required">
      Your required is wrong
    </div>
    <div ng-message="pattern">
      Your pattern is wrong
    </div>
    <div ng-message="minlength">
      Your minlength is wrong
    </div>
    <div ng-message="onlyAfterAllOtherPassedValidation">
      Your onlyAfterAllOtherPassedValidation
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```